# Get data using row / col reference from two column values in another data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

df1

```
       Date    APA     AR  BP-GB   CDEV  ...    WLL    WPX     XEC    XOM  CL00-USA
0 2018-01-01  42.22  19.00  5.227  19.80  ...  26.48  14.07  122.01  83.64     60.42
1 2018-01-02  44.30  19.78  5.175  20.00  ...  27.37  14.31  125.51  85.03     60.37
2 2018-01-03  45.33  19.78  5.242  20.33  ...  27.99  14.39  126.20  86.70     61.63
3 2018-01-04  46.84  19.80  5.300  20.37  ...  28.11  14.44  128.66  86.82     62.01
4 2018-01-05  46.39  19.44  5.296  20.12  ...  27.79  14.24  127.82  86.75     61.44
```

df2

```
        Date Ticker Event_Type Event_Description   Price  add
0 2018-11-19    XEC        M&A               REN   88.03    1
1 2018-03-28    CXO        M&A              RSPP  143.25    1
2 2018-08-14   FANG        M&A               EGN  133.75    1
3 2019-05-09    OXY        M&A               APC   56.33    1
4 2019-08-26   PDCE        M&A              SRCI   29.65    1
```

My goal is to update df2.['add'] by using df2['Ticker'] and df2['Date'] to pull the value from df1 ... so for example the first row in df2 is XEC on 2018-11-19... the code needs to first look at df1[XEC] and then pull the value that matches the 2018-11-19 row in df[Date]

My attempt was:

```
df_Events['add'] = df_Prices.loc[[df_Prices['Date']==df_Events['Date']],[df_Prices.columns==df_Events['Ticker']]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1.melt(value_vars=df1.columns.tolist()[1:], id_vars='date', value_name="add", var_name='Ticker').reset_index(), how='left')`
```

This should change df1 `Tickers` columns to a single column, and than merge the values in that column to df2.

Comment: Thanks, the result looks like it's missing code to return only the row that matches df2['date']... for example my df1 has 447 rows so the above duplicates each row 447 times and the "add" then has all 447 values.

Comment: @Jaiale1 You are right. I've forgot to reset the newly created index of `Date`. Edited that now.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach may be as below (I had started looking at it, so I am putting here even though you have accepted the answer)

First convert dates into datetime object in both dataframes & set it as index ony in the first one (code below)

```
df1['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
```

Then use apply to get the values for each of the columns.

```
df2['add']=df2.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[(x['Date']),(x['Ticker'])], axis=1)
```

This will work only if dates & values for all tickers exist in both dataframes (hence will throw as 'KeyError'